.NET 6 - Accessing Rx Subject Element Concurrently And RAM Optimization While Using TCPClient
I have a .NET 6 project that reads market data from remote socket via TCPClient, process the data, and streams the processed data as socket. But the trick is, there are 2 markets. One is for delayed (15 mins delay) and the other one is for real-time prices. This means I need to make connection twice. But I am not making the same connection twice. I have different host and port for real-time and delayed socket connections.
I am opening a global connection to these sockets. Which means, when the program starts the connection for real time and delayed market prices are being done. When a user request a real-time or delayed socket data, program accesses the concurrent dictionary that is already filled by relevant connection (since we have 2 connections for delayed and real-time data) and return the data. With this, I am not opening a connection to the remote socket server everytime a user request a data and wait for dictionary to fill.
And these connections should be open indefinitely since there may come a new data at any time. Here is my class and function that is responsible for connection to the socket:
 public class BaseIdealSocketService {
   private readonly Subject<PriceLog> _subjectPrice;
   private readonly object _lock;
   public ConcurrentDictionary<string, PriceLog> _price;

   public BaseIdealSocketService(string server, int port, string username, string password, ICacheService cacheService) {
     _subjectPrice = new Subject<PriceLog>();
     _lock = new object();
     //Price log is processed data, string is the code of the stock (AAPL, META etc.)
     _price = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, PriceLog>();
   }

   // This method is responsible from sending the processed data through socket
   public async Task<IObservable<PriceLog>> GetStreamPriceStocks() {
     return await Task.FromResult(_subjectPrice);
   }

   public async Task < IObservable < PriceLog >> GetStreamPriceStock(string code) {
     var filteredStocks = _subjectPrice.Where(priceLog => priceLog.Symbol == code);
     return filteredStocks.AsObservable();
   }

   // this is the function where my code connects to the remote socket server, receives data
   // and processes it. After process, the data is stored on concurrentdictionary and
   // subject.onnext is being called to notify the value is added or updated
   public async Task Start() {
     while (true) {
       try {
         retryDelay = 1000;
         ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType) 3072;
         using(var tcpClient = new TcpClient(_server, _port))
         using(var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()) {
           var bytesRead = 0;
           while (networkStream.CanRead) {
             var responseBuffer = new byte[1024]; // I set this up as 1024 for RAM performance
             bytesRead = await networkStream.ReadAsync(responseBuffer);
             var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBuffer.AsSpan(0, bytesRead));
             items = message.Split('|').Distinct().ToArray(); //data came as ....|.....|.....
             for (int i = 0; i < items.Length - 1; i++) {
               var item = items[i];

               if (!IsNewLine(items[i + 1])) {
                 item = item + items[i + 1];
               }

               /* 
                   some logic here
               */

               if (_price.TryGetValue(code, out
                   var price)) {
                 var priceLog = new PriceLog( /*data insertions*/ );
                 _price[code] = priceLog;
                 lock(_lock) {
                   _subjectPrice.OnNext(priceLog);
                 }
               } else {
                 var priceLog = new PriceLog( /*data insertions*/ );
                 _price.TryAdd(code, priceLog);

                 lock(_lock) {
                   _subjectPrice.OnNext(_price[code]);
                 }
               }

               await Task.Delay(50);
               i++;
             }
           }
         }
       }

       await Task.Delay(retryDelay);

       // Implement a backoff strategy to increase the delay between retries, up to a maximum value
       retryDelay = Math.Min(retryDelay * 2, 10000); // wait 10 seconds before reconnecting
     }
   }

   // sometimes data come into two line and I need to determine if the data has come fully or partial to concat it with the next line to make it complete
   private bool IsNewLine(string line) {
     // new line check logic
   }
 }

At Start() function, the concurrent dictionary(_price) and subject(_subjectPrice) are being filled with processed PriceLog data.
To start this Start() function for delayed and live socket data, I am calling these methods as follows on Program.cs:
connectionService.GetLiveSocketService().Start(); // real-time socket service
connectionService.GetSocketService().Start(); // delayed socket service

I am not awaiting them since they are meant to run indefinitely. I am just calling them as it is which means they are running on different threads.
And here is my socket connection function (to get processed data as socket stream:
 public async Task HandleStreamStocks(HttpContext context, UserType userType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     context.RequestAborted.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
     IMySocketService _socketService = userType == RealTime
         ? _idealConnectionService.GetLiveSocketService()
         : _idealConnectionService.GetSocketService();

     var webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

     var channel = (await _socketService.GetStreamPriceStocks()).AsChannelReader(2048); // here, the channel is empty (Items = 0) since I am sending this request from another thread
     await ProcessChannelAndSendData(webSocket, context, channel, cancellationToken);
}

private async Task ProcessChannelAndSendData(WebSocket webSocket, HttpContext context,
  ChannelReader < PriceLog > channel, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  try {
    if (context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested) return;
    while (!channel.Completion.IsCompleted && webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open) {
      if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested || context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested) {
        webSocket.Dispose();
        return;
      }
    }

    await foreach(var data in channel.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken)) {

      // some logic here for "data" manipulation

      string serializedData = SerializeData(data);
      byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedData);
      await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment < byte > (message), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true,
        cancellationToken);

      await Task.Delay(200, cancellationToken);
    }

    await webSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Channel completed", cancellationToken);
    webSocket.Dispose();
  } catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
    //close request received from client
    await webSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "An error has occurred",
      context.RequestAborted);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    await webSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, "An error has occurred",
      context.RequestAborted);
  }
}

When I want to send request to GetStreamPriceStocks() as shown above from another thread, the subject is empty. I have tried ReplaySubject and Synchronize but couldn't make it work, maybe I tried it wrongly.
I need to access the contents of the subject to return this data from socket and without opening new connection to the remote socket server each time a user requests socket data.
When I write Start() function to the constructor of BaseIdealSocketService class it works like a charm! The data is received by handlestremstocks requests.
To summarize my questions and problems:

How can I access the contents of subject form another thread?

Am I handling client disconnections correctly on ProcessChannelAndSendData() function?

My other concern is the RAM usage. Is there any way to reduce RAM usage other than reducing buffer size for Start() function that reads and processes data? Or any recommendations?


I am very new to the socket developing that's why any help would be appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

You don't need this code to do whatever it is you're trying to do. This code mixes up APIs that do the same thing and even includes hacks  like ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType) 3072; that were only used in .NET Framework 4.0, which didn't have bult-in support for either TLS1.2 or async/await. When you use ChannelReader you're either using .NET Core or .NET Framework 4.6.2 and that hack prevents you from using TLS1.3
